# Are there any efficient algorithm for "top hull"?

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer, convex-hull

for example, when points are given in form of (x-left, x-right, y) in x,y coordinate, ( 1 , 5 , 3), (2 , 4, 5) returns (1,2,3) , (2 ,4 ,5), (4,5,3)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because pure algorithmic questions should be handled by Computer Science and/or Math sites.

Comment: Are segments horizontal?

Comment: yes, all the segments are horizontal

Comment: (In the ex1, the third tuple should be *{8,10,5}*.) What about overlapping "top segments"? {1,10,5}, {2,8,6}, {7,9,5}? Keywords: (geometrical) visibility, paradigms in computational geometry, especially [line sweep](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest efficient ( O(N log N) ) way to solve this problem is with a "line sweep" algorithm.

Imagine sweeping a vertical line from left to right across the whole set, keeping track of the top-most segment that it crosses.  Whenever the top-most segment changes, it is an important event that could affect the top-hull.  It would be easy to calculate the top-hull from a list of these changes.

Notice that these important events can only happen at the x positions where one of the input segments starts or ends.  Instead of smoothly sweeping the line, therefore, we only need to consider what happens at these x positions.  So:

1. Generate a list of all the start and end events for the segments.  For a segment { 1, 2, 5}, for example would generate events {1, start 5}, {2, end 5}
2. Create a max heap to keep track of the top-most segment.
3. Sort all the events by x position, and process them in order.  For events with the same x position, do the start events first.  This ensures that you process each segment's start event before its end event.
4. For each x position in the list, process all the events with that x position as a unit.  For each start event {x, start y} add y to the heap.  For each event {x, end y}, remove y from the heap.
5. When you're done processing the events for an x position, the biggest element in the heap is the y position of the top-hull until the next x position in the list.

Comment: Extremely simple and elegant. I have seen this once before in an algorithms course, but here my thought process quickly became skewed once I thought of using a BST. I'm grateful that you commented to remind me of this.

Comment: how to remove specified element from the max heap? I've known that max heap only have 'pop' function, deleting max-value in the heap.

Comment: @pearsonboy  It depends on the kind of heap you're using.  If you're using an array-based heap, then the easiest way is to remember the start event object you pushed and then mark it invalid when it ends.  Then you just pop invalid nodes whenever you see them at the top

Comment: Or if you want to use an array of simple integers (not objects), then you can use a heap of added numbers, and a heap of removed numbers, and pop from both whenever their top elements match

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solved the problem using your algorithm. and I found that this kind of problem is related to "skyline problem".

Answer (score 4):

A straightforward greedy algorithm solves this neatly.
Sort your segments by y-coordinate, descending; ca;; this list `seg`.  Now ...

```
top_hull = [empty set]
while seg is not empty
    head = seg.pop()    // pop off the highest segment.
    top_hull += head
    for each segment in seg
        remove the interval (head.xleft, head.y-left) from segment
```

Note that interval removal can some in a few cases:

```
`head`'s interval does not overlap `segment`
    no action
`head`'s interval contains `segment`
    remove segment
`segments`'s interval contains `head` (both ends stick out
    split segment into the two remaining pieces.
`head`'s interval overlaps one end of `segment`
    truncate segment
```

Depending on your implementation language, there may be excellent support packages for interval algebra.

Answer (score 2):

Prunes answer has the right idea, but I feel it doesn't do justice to explaining how to check interval overlap. In fact, that portion of the algorithm runs in quadratic time `O(n^2)` since it forms all `n^2` pairs at some point, which is unnecessary. What I would do-

### Queuing

First, create a max-heap from your list of segments, with the y-coordinate as its key. You can extract and remove the max in `O(logn)` time, so this plays out to be the same time complexity as sorting, just with popping builtin.

```
heap = max_heap(segement_list)
output = []
while heap is not empty
    segment = heap.pop() # max / highest

    # trim / split segment
    # append trimmed segment(s)
```

### Intersections

Now we just need to trim the segment. Instead of pairing it against every other segment and trimming them as necessary, we'll use another data structure to allow us to quickly query for potential intersections. We'll store each added segment in a binary search tree, with the lower x-coordinate as its key. We can then traverse this tree looking for the largest segment (by lower x-coordinate) less than or equal to the segment we are about to add.

For the sake of making the following paragraphs less bloated with technical details, lets just get the implementation details of two key comparisons out of the way. Assume segment `a` has a smaller `lower_x` value than `b` (because in the following paragraph, we'll always know which is smaller).

```
# boolean- do `a` and `b` intersect
function intersects(a, b)
    return a.upper_x >= b.lower_x

# boolean- is `b` a subsegment of `a`
function is_subsegment(a, b)
    return a.upper_x >= b.upper_x
```

We'll also need three transformations, using the same `a` and `b` definition-

```
function merge(a, b)
    a.upper_x = b.upper_x

function trim_left(a, b)
    a.upper_x = b.lower_x

function trim_right(a, b)
    b.lower_x = a.upper_x
```

Returning to the idea of querying a BST- take `left_segment` obtained when querying for our segment `segment`, and see if they intersect. If they intersect, check if `segment` `is_subsegment` of `left_segment`. If it is, abort and `continue` on to the next segment in the heap. Otherwise, provided they intersect, we'll need to `trim_right` `segment`. Regardless of intersection or not, we'll then handle any right side intersections. Afterwards, we can `merge` the modified `segment` (actually `subsegment`, as you'll see) with `left_segment` if they overlapped.

The `left_segment` is the only segment that can overlap from the left, because we merge all overlapping segments as they are inserted into the BST. However, this does not hold for the right side, since our `segment` has yet to be trimmed from the right. We'll need to handle trimming incrementally.

Take `right_segment` to be the next segment after `left_segment` in the tree (in-order traversal). Make a copy of `segment` called `subsegment`. If `subsegment` intersects `right_segment`, trim_left it, insert `subsegment` into the output array, merge the two segments, and remove `right_segment` from the BST. Otherwise, just insert `subsegment` into the array. Now we may merge `subsegment` with `left_segment`, if they overlapped. If they did not, insert `subsegment` into the BST, and assign the variable `left_segment` to it.

Now we repeat this process, until we break out from `segment` being a `is_subsegment` of `left_segment`. Afterwards, we repeat the *entire* process with the next segment from the heap.

### Analysis

We know that forming our max-heap and popping the max `n` times will result in `O(nlogn)` time complexity. The tricky part is figuring out the time complexity for processing the intersections. Observe that for each segment we handle, after all `subsegment`s have been handled and merged, we will have increased the size of our BST overall by at most one. This is because all of our `subsegment`s get merged together each iteration, so they end up forming one big segment. This means our BST is no larger than `n`, so querying into and removing / inserting into the BST takes `O(logn)` time.

Also note that for each segment inserted into the BST, it will only every intersect another segment once- because when it does, the two (or more) will merge into a single new segment. The exception to this is when a segment is a subsegment of its `left_segment`, but in that case we abort without emitting any new segments anyways, so its +0 net change in size anyways. Using this knowledge, combined with the prior observation that each segment ultimately contributes at most one new segment to the BST, we can conclude that there will be at most `O(n)` intersections, and thus insertions / deletions. So `O(nlogn)` time to maintain our BST.

Given the rest of our operations are constant time, our overall time complexity is `O(nlogn)`, instead of `O(n^2)` when brute forcing for intersections and trimming.

Comment: Nice work!  +1.  I didn't have time to properly reduce my outline to `n log n`; I'm glad you took care of the heavy lifting.

Comment: Nice write up and works fine, but check my line sweep answer.  You'll want to add that general technique to your toolkit, since it's very useful for lots of 2D problems (often in combination with Trapezoidal decomposition).

Comment: `line sweep answer` a technique to consider - I'd still do the sweep top to bottom. One point that may warrant pondering is whether to process endpoints with like y-coordinate in order of, say, increasing x, or segments in order of increasing start, decreasing end, keeping a *current segment* and ignoring any endpoint contained therein.